# memorystream(byte[]) vs memorystream.write(byte[])

Tags: c#

I needed to put a byte to a memory stream so initially, I used:

```
byte[] Input;
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    mem.Write(Input, 0, (int)Input.Length);
    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(mem);
    ...
}
```

I wanted to use the Streamreader to read lines from a text file.

It didn't work.

Then I used

```
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(Input))
```

instead and removed

```
mem.Write(Input, 0, (int)Input.Length);
```

It worked. I don't know why. Why did it work?

Comment: If all you want is to read text **files**, you should just use `StreamReader` and not mess around with MemoryStream at all...

Comment: With regard to your question: `MemoryStream.Write` changes the stream read/write position to be **behind** the data written into the MemoryStream (i.e. the end of the stream), in which case reading from it afterwards will not yield anything. Using the MemoryStream constructor with the byte array keeps the stream position at zero, hence reading works.Try your first approach again, but set the MemoryStream position back to zero before using the StreamReader, and it should work too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But from what i have seen in other posts, they use memory stream. If it was from a file path it's okay but I need to read from a byte array.

Comment: Okay, then see my second comment :)

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first approach, you use `mem.Write(Input, 0, (int)Input.Length);`. Note that [MemoryStream.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.write?view=netframework-4.7.2) sets the stream read/write position behind the written data. In your example case this is equivalent with a position signifying the end of the stream. Trying to read from the MemoryStream again will not return any data, as the MemoryStream read/write position is at the end of the stream.

In your second approach, you passed the `Input` byte array as argument to the MemoryStream constructor. Providing the byte array through the constructor not only will make MemoryStream use this byte array, but more importantly it keeps the initial stream position of zero. Thus, when trying to read from the MemoryStream initialized in this way, the data contained in the input byte array will be returned as expected.

**How to fix the problem with the first approach?**

You can make the first approach with [MemoryStream.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.write?view=netframework-4.7.2) working by simply setting the MemoryStream position back to the intended/original value (in your example case it would be zero) after writing the data to the MemoryStream:

```
byte[] Input;
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    mem.Write(Input, 0, (int)Input.Length);

    mem.Position = 0;

    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(mem))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```